# libmysqlclient hangs on vmsplice()

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, system-calls, libmysql

I am running an executable that uses libmysqlclient.so.15 on a 64bit kernel & 32bit user space compatibility mode.

Once in a while, my program hangs on something from libmysql:

```
#0  0xf7f01430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf7b451e3 in vmsplice () from /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#2  0xf7e72c10 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#3  0xf7d409db in vio_read_buff () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#4  0xf7d41cc9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#5  0xf7d42083 in my_net_read () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#6  0xf7d3be7c in cli_safe_read () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#7  0xf7d3c585 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#8  0xf7d3a954 in mysql_real_query () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#9  0xf7d12935 in mysql_query () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
#10 0x080a37a9 in dbd_mysql_query (result=0xde32d58,
```

We are running on 2.6.26-2-amd64 #1 SMP debian machine.

I have no idea what it is, and it happens once in a while.

S.O.S!!!!

thanks